# Applying user-defined filter using GAS (implementing a table search feature)

Tags: search, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I'm trying to implement a search feature in my Google Sheet using a script and falling at the last hurdle. I'd just like to know if anyone can see what might be going wrong in the script?

I am very close to the expected result using the code below (the expected result being that the table is automatically filtered by the user's criteria entered in cell B2), however, the filter doesn't seem to actually get applied.

This is what I'm seeing from running the current script:
 - The onEdit is detecting the change to cell B2
 - The filter is being cleared of any existing criteria
 - A new filter (on the header in cell B4) is being created using the (user defined) criteria from cell B2
 - **The filter does not get applied. The user must manually open the filter and hit "apply"**

Obviously, the part in bold shouldn't happen. It needs to automatically apply.

```
function onEdit(evt)
{
  var range = evt.range;

  if (range.getRow() == 2 && range.getColumn() == 2)
  {
    ClearFilter();
    Utilities.sleep(200);
    ApplyFilter();
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.log("Edit out of range");
  }
}


function ClearFilter() 
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(2);
}


function ApplyFilter() 
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B4').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenTextContains('=INDIRECT("BWLRankings!B2")')
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), criteria);
};
```

Comment: If you avoid the indirection (i.e. read the current value of B2 on the other sheet and set that), does it work as expected?

Comment: Unfortunately not - same deal. If I change it to =B2, it's the same result

Comment: I mean, use the script to *read* the value of B2 (i.e. `var value = ss.getSheetByName('BWLRankings').getRange('B2').getValue();`) and use that actual value (rather than a formula)

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry - totally misunderstood that. It does appear to work! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your original code is that you are setting the wrong filter criteria type. If we look at the available methods of the [`FilterCriteriaBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder.html), we note that there is a method [`whenFormulaSatisfied`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder.html#whenFormulaSatisfied(String)).

Since `'=INDIRECT("BWLRankings!B2")'` is a *formula*, and not a plain text / numeric *value*, you should use it instead of [`whenTextContains`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder.html#whentextcontainstext). Your original filter was actually being applied, but because no cell values in the column contained the literal text `=INDIRECT("BWLRankings!B2")`, no cells were filtered out.